# How to connect programmatically to the Ruby debugger to create a plugin for Sublime Text 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, sublimetext2

I want to develop a plugin for Sublime Text 2 to add a Ruby debugger inside the editor. I was looking some documentation on how to connect to the debugger but I could not find nothing really good. I want to know if there is an API or if its possible to connect to debugger programmatically. I would like to use this project as the debugger backend https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger

Answer (score 0):

Since Python is required to write plugins for ST2, you can't hook into https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/blob/master/bin/rdebug and just start studying it's API to do your stuff.

But you can do a popen (see http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) on the debugger executable and drive it like you'd do it normally. This isn't very elegant but I'm afraid that's the only solution available since you're locked with Python.

From there, I'd probably write some python api to handle the basic operations programmatically, like the following pseudo code :

```
class RubyDebugger:
  def __init__(self, debugger_path):
    # Popen stuff, consider looking for the idiomatic way of doing that :) 
    self.debugger = os.popen ...

  def breakpoint(self, file, line_number)
    self.debugger.write "breakpoint " + file + ":" + line_number
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I cannot figure out a way to connect to a running Rails App that is using the debugger gem. Do you know how to  do this using the rdebug client?